# Receiving error while trying to debug in QtProject

Tags: compiling, qt, c++, debugging

I installed the latest version of [the QtProject](http://qt-project.org) so now I can debug `C++` code.

While trying to debug for the first time I got this error:

```
ptrace: Operation not permitted.

Could not attach to the process. Make sure no other debugger traces this process.
Check the settings of
/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
```

Answer (score 14):

On Ubuntu versions after 10.10 you'll run into this in more related applications, such as QtCreator. It is a security *feature* of Ubuntu that prevent the debugger to attach to processes not owned by him.

This is filed as a [bug #3509 against QtCreator](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-3509). To work around this issue, do this:

- temporary solution (won't survive a reboot):

  ```
   echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
  ```
- In a file `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` (should already exist), change the value of `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope` to `0` and then reload the configuration: `sudo sysctl -p`.

I'm explicitly posting the temporary solution, as you probably don't want to keep this feature disabled on a regular machine for security reasons.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem while running the project in terminal. Just uncheck (or check - run - uncheck if it is for some reason unchecked) the box "Run in terminal" in "Projects" (on the left bar) - "Run" tab - "Run" section.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me debugging now starts in QTCreators application output.

Comment: Voting this one up because it's the easiest solution if you don't need to see the terminal output from your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can change gdb capabilities with

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_ptrace=eip /usr/bin/gdb
```

man capabilities tells cap_sys_ptrace gives right to

```
Trace  arbitrary  processes  using ptrace(2); apply get_robust_list(2)
to arbitrary processes; inspect processes using kcmp(2).
```

See also man cap_from_text.

This is a solution that is not removed by reboot, but it is not completely safe either. I'm open to suggestions how to do this permanently and safely.

Answer (score -4):

Just open QtCreator via a Terminal with root permissions; it worked for me.

```
sudo qtcreator
```

Comment: It reveals big security hole.